# Is there a way to determine if a value is in an array as well as the location of its position in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am relatively new with C I am tasked with creating a function that uses an array to take in different GPA values and make various calculations with them. One of the tasks required includes determining if a value is stored in the array and its position in the array. I was just wondering what the best way would be to do this? Previously answered questions I've found can determine if something is in an array, but not its position.

The full code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define SIZE 1000 //define max # of GPAs to be input



void mainFunction()
{

  //create array variables
  int x = 0.0;
  float gpas[1000] = {0};


  //used in switch
  char switchLetter;


  //used for calculations
  float sum = 0.0;
  float average;
  int counter =0;


  // used for highest/lowest calculations
  float lowest, highest, buf;


  //used for arranging array in ascending order
  int a, j;


  //used for determining if a value is in an array
  float value;


  //create menu
  printf("\n");
  printf("************************************\n");
  printf("**           MAIN MENU            **\n");
  printf("************************************\n");
  printf("A. Enter GPA\n");
  printf("B. Display Average of all GPA's\n");
  printf("C. Display Highest GPA\n");
  printf("D. Display Lowest GPA\n");
  printf("E. Display the adjusted average\n");
  printf("F. See if a certain GPA was entered\n");
  printf("G. Display the contents of the array\n");
  printf("Q. Quit\n");
  printf("************************************\n");



  //create switch statement 
  do{
  //used to control switch
  scanf("%c", &switchLetter);


  switch(switchLetter)
  {
//*********************************************************//
    case 'A':
    for(x=0; x<1000; x++)
      {
      scanf("%f", &gpas[x]);
      counter++;
      sum += gpas[x];
          if (gpas[x] >= 3.5)
          {
            printf("\nNice Work!\n");
          }

          if (gpas[x] <= 2.0)
          {
            printf("\nYou need to study harder :() \n");
          }
      }

            for (x = 0; x < SIZE; ++x) 
              {

            for (j = x + 1; j < SIZE; ++j)
            {
             if (gpas[x] > gpas[j])
             {
             a =  gpas[x];
              gpas[x] = gpas[j];
              gpas[j] = a;
             }
             }
              }          
    break;
//*********************************************************//
    case 'B':
    {
      sum += gpas[x];
      average = (sum / counter);
      printf("\nAverage = %.2lf\n", average);
      break;
    }
//*********************************************************//
    case 'C':
    {
      highest = gpas[0];

      for (x = 1; x < SIZE; x++) 
        {
          if (highest < gpas[x])
            highest = gpas[x];
          }

      printf("\nhighest = %.2lf\n", highest);
      break;
    }
//*********************************************************//
    case 'D':
    {
      lowest = gpas[0];

      for (x =1; x < SIZE; x++)
        {
          if (lowest > gpas[x])
          lowest = gpas[x];
        }
         printf("\nlowest = %.2lf\n\n", lowest);
         break;
    }
//*********************************************************//
    case 'E':
    {

      gpas[x] = (gpas[x] - gpas[0]);
      sum += gpas[x];
      average = (sum / counter);
      printf("\nAverage = %.2lf\n", average); 
      break;
    }    
//*********************************************************//
    case 'F':
    {
      printf("Enter Value:\n");
      scanf("%f", &value);
      if (value == gpas[x])
      {
        printf("\ntrue\n");
      }
      break;
    }
//*********************************************************//
    case 'G':
    printf("Contents of Array: \n");
    for(x=0; x<counter; x++)  
      {  
      printf("%.2f, ", gpas[x]);  
      } 
      break;
//*********************************************************//
    case 'Q':
    return;
  }

  }
while (x<= SIZE);
}



int main(void) 
{
  mainFunction();
}
```

Anything helps, thank you :)

Comment: Is the array sorted?

Comment: By definition, if you've discovered an item is *in* the array, you've determined the position in which that discovery resides. You can't get to the former without the latter.

Comment: How do you know that `scanf("%f", &gpas[x]);` succeeds? (or any other of the calls to `scanf`)? What happens if there was a stray alpha-character in the input? How would you know if a *matching-failure* occurs? In the event of a *matching-failure*, what value does `gpas[x]` hold?. Moral of the story - `scanf` (or any other input function) cannot be used correctly unless you ***check the return*** -- for every input. E.g. `if (scanf("%f", &gpas[x]) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid float input.\n", stderr); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it would be:

```
int findElement(int array[], int arraySize, int gpa)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
  {
     // If you find the element, return its index
     if (array[i] == gpa) return i;
  }
  // If no index was found, return -1
  return -1;
}
```

Since arrays can't have negative indexes, returning -1 would signal that the element could not be found. Any other value would signal that the element was found, and what its index is.

Comment: "Since arrays can't have negative indexes" - yes that is true, but it is possible to use a negative index on a pointer that's the result of a decayed array that has had an arbitrary offset applied to it. In other words `array[-1]` in this context *could* be valid.

Comment: True. I was considering that as I was typing it but he said he was relatively new to c so I didn't feel it was worth mentioning that. May have been a mistake on my part.

Comment: Had to adjust for my code but works great! Thank you so much!